# What test for comparing results before and after an intervention?

Tags: statistical-significance, mcnemar-test

I'm writing a paper in which we show a doctor some lab results for a group of patients and ask him to say yes or no to a diagnosis blindly. Then, I tell him the patient's history and other important information, ask him to look at the same lab results, and ask him to do the diagnosis again. With this information, I can build two 2x2 contingency tables, with true positives and negatives and false positives and negatives, to obtain sensitivity and specificity results for each contingency table.

I want to see if the changes are statistically significant. What test should I use to calculate it? I know the distribution is not normal, so I guess a non-parametric test should be used. I looked a bit and think McNemars' test would be appropriate, but I don't know how to calculate it based on two contingency tables. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have results for just one doctor, or many doctors?

Comment: I have the results for two doctors. But I'm interested to compare the results from before and after the patients' history for one doctor. Like, is knowing the patients' history impactful or not in the decision making

Comment: Is you question about one doctor (before and after informing lab results) or more than one doctor?